# pandas Convert string Series to int Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble converting a string `Series` of integers and nulls to an integer `Series`. Coming from an R background, I'm not sure why this doesn't convert to `int` when I call `out.astype(int)`:

```
series = pd.Series([
  'Employee: Trump, Donald ID: 81780 Time Zone: Pacific',   'some text',
  'Employee: Obama, Barack ID: 84428 Time Zone: Pacific',   'some text'
])
out = series.str.split(
    ' ID: '
).str.get(1).str.split(
    ' Time Zone: '
).str.get(0)
out.astype(int)
```

returns:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: There is no missing value correspondence to integer type. `NaN` can only be float.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry for duplicate question. Is there a best practice around this? Should I just use float for any 'numeric' data? In R, I use numeric / float for both integer and float, because there aren't any drawbacks for most practical purposes.

Comment: If most of the users are not complaining too much about the case, I guess it is the same situation here. Not sure if it is the best practice though.